# Provide access to instance in event handler

Tags: oop, dart

For now, I'm trying to learn dart language, and stuck with a problem. Firstly, some code. _clickHandler and _constructNode are method of same class

```dart
  EventListener _clickHandler = (Event e){
    this.setActive(e.currentTarget);
  };

  /* Render methods */

  Element _constructNode(Node node){
      DivElement nodeContainer = new DivElement();
      nodeContainer.id = "node-${node.id.toString()}";
      nodeContainer.classes.add("node");


      SpanElement nodeTitle = new SpanElement();
      nodeTitle.text = node.value;
      nodeTitle.addEventListener('click', this._clickHandler);

      nodeContainer.append(nodeTitle);

      return nodeContainer;
  }
```

So, _clickHandler breakes on "this":

```dart
receiver 'this' is not in scope
```

How I can use "this" pointer in event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess removing the `=` and `;` (at the end) will be sufficient to make your code work.

```dart
EventListener _clickHandler(Event e){
  this.setActive(e.currentTarget);
}
```

You make `_clickHandler` a field referencing a closure and in the closure you have no `this`. Changing it to a method will make it work as expected.

Comment: Thx. I completly forget about closures in that way.

Comment: Took me a few seconds until I saw it. I wondered why the method has a `;` a the end ;-)